# Adds additional constraints to the eager loading query

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called `vehicles` that has a one to many relationship with the table called `fuels`. A column in the `fuels` table is titled `cost`. When I get the vehicle model, how do I get the total fuel `cost` that have been accrued over the course of two particular days?

I tried this:

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::withSum([
    'fuels',
    'cost' => function ($query) use ($start, $end) {
        $query->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end]);
    }
])->get();
```

Comment: `table`, `relationship`. Did you think at least one second to give some context to the reader? What are you using? What technology? Why you don't even tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$vehicles = Vehicle::withSum(
    ['fuels' => fn($q) => $q->whereBetween('date', [$start, $end])],
    'cost'
)->get();
```